# Why can't I use a variable created using prompt() within a function?

Tags: javascript

Below is a function which should produce a random number between two numbers which are specified by the user. The equation works if I manually specify the numbers. But if I use the prompt function it seems to produce a completely random number.

```
function randOm() {
    var high = prompt("high");
    var low = prompt("low");
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
}

document.write(randOm());
```

Comment: prompt() returns you a string, so you have to convert it before use it in math-operations

Comment: If you use console.log() to reveal what the prompt has gathered it appears to be an integer. Why is this the case? Also why does the equation not error and say NaN?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `parseFloat` to convert it to a `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the results of the prompt in numbers, because it returns strings:

```
return Math.floor(Math.random() * ((+high) - (+low) + 1)) + (+low);
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` is known to return `string`, hence u have to `convert` the `string to integer` before performing your operations.And another disadvantage is that, if the user enters any characters like "hello" or "hi" in the prompt box, your function might return `NaN`, because cannot parse characters to numbers.

Script:

```js
function randOm() {
    var high = prompt("high");
    var low = prompt("low");
    var h=parseInt(high);
    var l=parseInt(low);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (h - l + 1)) + l;
}

document.write(randOm());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Number.isNaN(high) || Number.isNaN(low)){
    alert ("both entries must be numbers!");
}
else{
    low = parseFloat(low);
    high = parseFloat(high);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (high - low + 1)) + low;
}
```

Comment: If you use console.log() to reveal what the prompt has gathered it appears to be an integer. Why is this the case?
Also why does the equation not error and say NaN?